# PDO FetchAll from mysql echo data in table

Tags: php, mysql

Working on a Highscore system in PHP. To get data from MySQL database I use this code.

```
<?php
$sql_query = "SELECT id,name, exp FROM user ORDER by exp DESC";
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=game', 'root', 'pass');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $rst = $conn->query($sql_query);
    $users= $rst->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    echo '' . json_encode($users) . '';
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}
?>
```

Output from that code looks like:

```
[{"id":"1","name":"Player","exp":"22060"}
```

I need to echo that data in  tags separately. For example.

```
<td><?php echo $users->name ?></td>
<td><?php echo $users->exp ?></td>
```

Comment: side-note: I'm under the impression you guys picked the wrong "original" question in the duplicate vote ;-)

Comment: @Volkerk Looking again at their code, your comment makes a good point :) I just retracted my vote

Comment: Oooops, I see what you're saying @VolkerK

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php
$sql_query = "SELECT id,name, exp FROM user ORDER by exp DESC";
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=game', 'root', 'pass');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $rst = $conn->query($sql_query);
    $users= $rst->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    foreach($users as $user) {
        echo "<td>{$user->name}</td>";
        echo "<td>{$user->exp}</td>";
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
}
?>
```

Comment: Why does putting the loop in the `try` make this work?

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: @JayBlanchard It doesn't make it work, it just lets you catch the exception before php stops running! Check this link out: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp

Comment: You can actually catch the exceptions and handle them gracefully without putting your display code in the `try`.